# Spring Batch - Load properties from database table

Tags: spring, key-value

I have a requirement in my spring batch where I have to load few key value properties from a database table. Is this possible? The job runs in a stand alone environment and not in a container.

Please let me know if you have a solution for this. `I am in a secured environment and that is the reason I have not shared the code initially. Anyways below is what I have. Below are my properties

```
<bean id="properties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:EnvConfig.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:DatabaseConfig.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:WebServiceConfig.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="properties" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="properties">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter"
            factory-method="getProperties">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <ref bean="sam-datasource" />
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg value="PTTMCDB.PROPERTY" />  <!-- DB Table -->
                    <constructor-arg value="PROPERTYNAME" />  <!-- DB Key Column -->
                    <constructor-arg value="PROPERTYVALUE" /> <!-- DB Value Column -->
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is where I am reading the properties fetched from DB.

```
<bean id="emailReaderUtil"
    class="mailreader.pop3.EmailReaderUtil">
    <property name="popServerHost" value="${pop3.popServerHost}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: http://www.albinsblog.com/2014/07/loading-configuration-properties-from.html#.VrM9fLJ97IU

Comment: http://pawel-malczyk.pl/wordpress/?p=540

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I am still not able to fetch the property values from DB. Are you sure this can be done outside the container in a stand alone application?

Comment: Please can you show what you have tried so far. You are more likely to get an answer here if you can follow guidelines in these links http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Your problem might be due to multiple  `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer ` Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686635/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-my-applicationc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697050/multiple-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-at-the-same-time