# Spring unable to resolve placeholder property from a default property file

Tags: java, spring, annotations, property-files

I searched around on stackoverflow but i do not see a solution for my usecase.

I am facing an issue when i try to add a common property file for default values

Currently we have only environment specific property files in the app-context.xml specified as follows:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:env_properties/${DEPLOY_ENV}/app.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </bean>
```

I added a default_app.properties file to avoid duplication of properties across all environments. The change is as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:env_properties/default_app.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:env_properties/${DEPLOY_ENV}/app.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

I am accessing the properties using the @Value annotation in the classes
Eg: @Value("${is_feature_enabled}")

This works perfectly fine when defined the Environment specific property files. However it throws the following exception when the property is only specified in the default_app.properties file

The exception is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private boolean 
com.XXXXXX.YYY.ZZZZ.SomePackage.SomeClass.is_feature_enabled; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'is_feature_enabled' in string value 
"${is_feature_enabled}"
```

**Please Note**: Am able to successfully reference the property defined in the default property file as a constructor argument for a bean defined in the app-context.xml. Am facing this issue only when I try to reference it in a class using @Value

Appreciate any thoughts or insights. Thanks

**Updated per Comment** I access the property by Value like this
@Value("${is_feature_enabled}")

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686635/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-my-applicationc
and this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697050/multiple-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-at-the-same-time

Comment: Can you add an example of how you reference a property in a class using `@Value` annotation?

Comment: I did go through those links but I do not believe that is the issue. I do not have multiple PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer and also if that were the case, then my Environment specific property should have failed as well in @Value use case

Comment: I have added the example for @Value